# Message queue error: No message of desired type

Tags: c, unix, message-queue

I am trying to understand how message queues work. I created this little program where the child process sends a message to the parent process. Most of the times, it works, but sometimes I would recieve the error: `Error parent:  No message of desired type`. I tried also to `wait` for the child process to finish, but I would still get the error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    struct msg{
        long mtype;
        char text[100];
    };

    int key = ftok(".", 10);
    int qid = msgget(key, 0666|IPC_CREAT);

    int pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0){
        struct msg send;
        send.mtype = 1;
        strcpy(send.text, "hello");
        if(msgsnd(qid, (void*)&send, strlen(send.text), IPC_NOWAIT)<0){
             printf("Error child: ");
        }
    }
    else{
        struct msg recieve;
        if(msgrcv(qid, (void*)&recieve, 100, 1, IPC_NOWAIT)<0){
             perror("Error parent: ");
        };
        printf("%s\n", recieve.text);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/msgrcv.html

> The argument msgflg specifies the action to be taken if a message of the desired type is not on the queue. These are as follows:
>
> - If (msgflg & IPC_NOWAIT) is non-zero, the calling thread will return immediately with a return value of -1 and errno set to [ENOMSG]
>   ...

You're specifying `IPC_NOWAIT` which means you're not giving the child process enough time to produce any message. If you drop that from the parameter `msgflg`, i.e.

```
if(msgrcv(qid, (void*)&recieve, 100, 1, 0) < 0)
```

The parent process will block until something is available in the queue.